# clone html table form with creating total column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a clone of each line input and add them up at every line input and then sum of all the input. ( jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/9LruyLrn/2/ )

For example as follows:
[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btnDel_3').click(function () {
    if (confirm("Last row will be remove ?"))
        {
            var num = $('.clonedInput_3').length;
            $('#rab' + num).slideUp(25, function () {$(this).remove();
            if (num -1 === 1)
                $('#btnDel_3').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#btnAdd_3').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "Add");
                $('#btnAdd_3').attr('disabled', false).text("Add");});
        }
    return false;
});
$('#btnAdd_3').attr('disabled', false);
$('#btnDel_3').attr('disabled', true);

$('#btnAdd_3').click(function () {
    var num = $('.clonedInput_3').length, 
    newNum  = new Number(num + 1), 
    newElem = $('#rab' + num).clone().attr('id', 'rab' + newNum).fadeIn(25); 
    newElem.find('.ket_1').attr('id', 'ket' + newNum + '_1').attr('name', 'ket' + newNum + '_1').val('');
    newElem.find('.input_1').attr('id', 'rab' + newNum + '_1').attr('name', 'rab' + newNum + '_1').val('');
    newElem.find('.input_2').attr('id', 'rab' + newNum + '_2').attr('name', 'rab' + newNum + '_2').val('');
    newElem.find('.input_3').attr('id', 'rab' + newNum + '_3').attr('name', 'rab' + newNum + '_3').val('');
    newElem.find('.input_4').attr('id', 'rab' + newNum + '_4').attr('name', 'rab' + newNum + '_4').val('');
    newElem.find('.sum').attr('id', 'sum' + newNum + '_1').attr('name', 'sum' + newNum + '_1').val('');
    $('#rab' + num).after(newElem);
    $('#ket' + newNum + '_1').focus();
    $('#btnDel_3').attr('disabled', false);
}); 
});
</script>
<form >
<fieldset style="width:75%;margin: 0 auto;">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Total</td> <!-- place for all total row and column will be appear hear-->
    <td colspan="3"><input type="text" id="total" name="total" disabled="disabled" size="20" placeholder="total column value" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="rab1" class="clonedInput_3">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Detail</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="ket_1"   id="ket1_1" name="ket1_1" size="20" maxlength="80" onfocus="coloring(this.id)" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="input_1" id="rab1_1" name="rab1_1" size="5" maxlength="20" onfocus="coloring(this.id)" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="input_2" id="rab1_2" name="rab1_2" size="5" maxlength="20" onfocus="coloring(this.id)" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="input_3" id="rab1_3" name="rab1_3" size="5" maxlength="20" onfocus="coloring(this.id)" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="input_4" id="rab1_4" name="rab1_4" size="5" maxlength="20" onfocus="coloring(this.id)" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="sum_1"   id="sum1_1" name="sum1_1" size="10" disabled="disabled" placeholder="total rows value" /></td><!-- place for total row-->
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<p>
  <button type="button" id="btnAdd_3" name="btnAdd_3" class="butadd3 btn btn-primary">Add</button>
  <button type="button" id="btnDel_3" name="btnDel_3" class="butdel3 btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
</p>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I have trouble when making a script about the total value of all input.
Who can help me please ?

Comment: Do you have a specific issue? This is a rather broad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#btnDel_3').click(function () {
           if (confirm("Last row will be remove ?")) {
               var num = $('.clonedInput_3').length;
               $('#rab' + num).slideUp(25, function () {
                   $(this).remove();
                   if (num - 1 === 1)
                       $('#btnDel_3').attr('disabled', true);
                   $('#btnAdd_3').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "Add");
                   $('#btnAdd_3').attr('disabled', false).text("Add");
               });
           }
           return false;
       });
       $('#btnAdd_3').attr('disabled', false);
       $('#btnDel_3').attr('disabled', true);

       $('#btnAdd_3').click(function () {
           var num = $('.clonedInput_3').length,
           newNum = new Number(num + 1),
           newElem = $('#rab' + num).clone().attr('id', 'rab' + newNum).fadeIn(25);
           newElem.find('.ket_1').attr('id', 'ket' + newNum + '_1').attr('name', 'ket' + newNum + '_1').val('');
           newElem.find('.input_1').attr('id', 'rab' + newNum + '_1').attr('name', 'rab' + newNum + '_1').val('');
           newElem.find('.input_2').attr('id', 'rab' + newNum + '_2').attr('name', 'rab' + newNum + '_2').val('');
           newElem.find('.input_3').attr('id', 'rab' + newNum + '_3').attr('name', 'rab' + newNum + '_3').val('');
           newElem.find('.input_4').attr('id', 'rab' + newNum + '_4').attr('name', 'rab' + newNum + '_4').val('');
           newElem.find('.sum').attr('id', 'sum' + newNum + '_1').attr('name', 'sum' + newNum + '_1').val('');
           $('#rab' + num).after(newElem);
           $('#ket' + newNum + '_1').focus();
           $('#btnDel_3').attr('disabled', false);


           $('.clonedInput_3').find('table').each(function () {
               total = 0;
               $(this).find('tr td:gt(1):lt(4)').each(function () {
                   if ($(this).find('input').val() != "") {
                       total = total + parseInt($(this).find('input').val(), 10);
                   }
               })
               $(this).find('tr td:last').find('input').val(total);
           });
            total = 0;
            $('.clonedInput_3').find('table tr td:last').each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('input').val() != "") {
                    total = total + parseInt($(this).find('input').val(), 10);
                }
           });
           $('#total').val(total);
       });

   });

<fieldset style="width:75%;margin: 0 auto;">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="text" id="total" name="total" disabled="disabled" size="20" placeholder="total all col" value="0"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="rab1" class="clonedInput_3">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Detail</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="ket_1"   id="ket1_1" name="ket1_1" size="8" maxlength="80" placeholder="Desc."  /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="input" id="rab1_1" name="rab1_1" size="4" maxlength="20" placeholder="Col 1"  /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="input" id="rab1_2" name="rab1_2" size="4" maxlength="20" placeholder="Col 2"  /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="input" id="rab1_3" name="rab1_3" size="4" maxlength="20" placeholder="Col 3"  /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="input" id="rab1_4" name="rab1_4" size="4" maxlength="20" placeholder="Col 4"  /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="sum_1"   id="sum1_1" name="sum1_1" size="15" disabled="disabled" placeholder="total row" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<p>
  <button type="button" id="btnAdd_3" name="btnAdd_3" class="butadd3 btn btn-primary">Add</button>
  <button type="button" id="btnDel_3" name="btnDel_3" class="butdel3 btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
</p>
```

Comment: thanks user1921115. but yours script can not change the value of Total column. https://jsfiddle.net/puspo/0hbzda9w/